# Guice and multithreading with ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, guice, executorservice

I'm trying to find a way to let `Callable`s be executed by an `ExecutorService`. The submitting thread should not wait for all `Callable`s to complete. That should be done by a separate thread. Those `Callable`s have a `FooService` injected by Guice. `FooService` is `SessionScoped`. To prevent `OutOfScopeException`s I use
`ServletScopes.transferRequest(Callable<T> callable)`.

Here is some sample code:

```
private void executeTasks() {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    List<Future<String>> futures = IntStream.of(32, 42, 52, 62)
            .mapToObj(i -> ServletScopes.transferRequest(taskFactory.create(i)))
            .map(task -> es.submit(task)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    es.shutdown();

    // Runnable resultHandlingTask = () -> {
        futures.parallelStream().forEach((Future<String> result) -> {
            try {
                LOGGER.debug("Result: " + result.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                LOGGER.debug("Exception while executing: ", ex);
            }
        });
    // };

    // new Thread(resultHandlingTask).start();
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

This code runs without exceptions. But when the separate thread is put into play to wait for the Future's and handle their result, there's an `ProvisionException` thrown by Guice.

**How to solve this? Or could this be a bug?**

For the sake of completeness, here is the code of `Task`:

```
public class Task implements Callable<String> {
    private final int id;

    private final Provider<FooService> fooServiceProvider;

    @Inject
    public Task(@Assisted int id, Provider<FooService> fooServiceProvider) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fooServiceProvider = fooServiceProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return fooServiceProvider.get().retrieveBarById(id);
    }
}
```

And here the stacktrace:

```
DEBUG: Thread-20: 2015-11-18 17:17:52,514 [TestPage.java:276]  -  Exception while executing: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at nl.mycompany.app.services.FooService.class(FooService.java:13)
  while locating nl.mycompany.app.services.FooService

1 error
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at nl.mycompany.app.modules.amodule.pages.TestPage.lambda$null$6(TestPage.java:274)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at nl.mycompany.app.modules.amodule.pages.TestPage.lambda$test2$7(BerichtenVerwerkenPage.java:272)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at nl.mycompany.app.services.FooService.class(FooService.java:13)
  while locating nl.mycompany.app.services.FooService

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    at nl.mycompany.app.services.BarTask.call(BarTask.java:24)
    at nl.mycompany.app.services.BarTask.call(BarTask.java:12)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletScopes$4.call(ServletScopes.java:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletScopes$2$1.get(ServletScopes.java:153)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.__callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: @Thomas To me it seems there might be somewhere a concurrency issue, because the exception isn't thrown all the time.

Comment: It looks like the build-in binding for the provider of `FooService` is part of the problem. Because there're no exceptions when `FooService` is injected as just a single instance (without the provider stuf). Also there're no exceptions when a `FooServiceProvider` implementing `Provider` (and set to `SessionScoped`) is bound. (In the above scenario a provider for `FooService` isn't really a necessity, but in my real life scenario it is.)

Comment: Can you make the FooService @Singleton scoped? I think this could fix the issue

Comment: @Thomas True, making `FooService` a singleton would workaround this issue. I kept the example code simple. The case I'm working on I've a service which uses a (session scoped) rest client which uses user settings (stored in db). Then the service also uses a message factory which needs to know the current user (of the current session). An other workaround would be getting rid of the 'waiting thread', which is commented out in the example code.